# Destructuring assignment in object creation

Tags: arrays, constructor, raku, destructuring, rakudo

As with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69137422/confusing-fmt-behavior-with-nested-lists), this is an area where I can't tell if I've encountered a bug or a hole in my understanding of Raku's semantics.  Last time it turned out to be a bug, but doubt lightning will strike twice!

In general, I know that I can pass named arguments to a function either with syntax that looks a lot like creating a Pair (e.g. `f :a(42)`) or with syntax that [looks a lot like](https://twitter.com/jnthnwrthngtn/status/1432395855819063301) flattening a Hash (e.g., `f |%h`). (see [argument destructuring](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#index-entry-destructuring_arguments) in the docs). Typically, these two are equivalent, even for non-Scalar parameters:

```
sub f(:@a) { dd @a }
my %h = a => [4, 2];
f :a([4,2]);  # OUTPUT: «Array element = [4, 2]»
f |%h;        # OUTPUT: «Array element = [4, 2]»
```

However, when constructing an object with the default `.new` constructor, these two forms seem to give different results:

```
class C { has @.a; }
my %h = a => [4, 2];
C.new: :a([4,2];  # OUTPUT: «C.new(a => ([[4, 2]])»
C.new: |%h;       # OUTPUT: «C.new(a => [[4, 2],])»
```

That is, passing `:a([4,2])` results in a two-element Array, but using the argument-flattening syntax results in a one-element Array containing a two-element Array.

Is this behavior intended?  If so, why?  And is there syntax I can use to pass `|%h` in and get the two-element Array bound to an `@`-sigiled attribute?  (I know using an `$`-sigiled attribute works, but I prefer the semantics of the `@`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is this behavior intended?

Yes. Parameter binding uses binding semantics, while attribute initialization uses assignment semantics. Assignment into an array respects `Scalar` containers, and the values of a `Hash` are `Scalar` containers.

> If so, why?

The intuition is:

- When calling a function, we're not going to be doing anything until it returns, so we can effectively lend the very same objects we pass to it while it executes. Thus binding is a sensible default (however, one can use `is copy` on a parameter to get assignment semantics).
- When creating a new object, it is likely going to live well beyond the constructor call. Thus copying - that is, assignment - semantics are a sensible default.

> And is there syntax I can use to pass |%h in and get the two-element Array bound to an @-sigiled attribute?

Coerce it into a `Map`:

```
class C { has @.a; }
my %h = a => [4, 2];
say C.new: |%h.Map;
```

Or start out with a `Map` in the first place:

```
class C { has @.a; }
my %h is Map = a => [4, 2];
say C.new: |%h;
```

Comment: Thanks -- a very helpful and comprehensive answer!  And, now that I understand the reasoning, I agree that assignment semantics make sense for objects as a default)