# Destructuring/list assignment with the `has` declarator

Tags: constructor, variable-assignment, raku, destructuring, rakudo

[I ran into the issues that prompted this question and my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69147382/destucturing-assignment-in-object-creation) at the same time, but decided the two questions deserve to be separate.]

The docs describe using [destructuring assignment](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-destructuring_assignment) with `my` and `our` variables, but don't mention whether it can be used with `has` variables.  But Raku is consistent enough that I decided to try, and it *appears* to work:

```
class C { has $.a; has $.b }
class D { has ($.a, $.b) }
C.new: :a<foo>;  # OUTPUT: «C.new(a => "foo", b => Any)»
D.new: :a<foo>;  # OUTPUT: «D.new(a => "foo", b => Any)»
```

However, this form seems to break attribute defaults:

```
class C { has $.a; has $.b = 42 }
class D { has ($.a, $.b = 42) }
C.new: :a<foo>;  # OUTPUT: «C.new(a => "foo", b => 42)»
D.new: :a<foo>;  # OUTPUT: «C.new(a => "foo", b => Any)»
```

Additionally, flipping the position of the default provides an error message that might provide *some* insight into what is going on (though not enough for me to understand if the above behavior is correct).

```
class D { has ($.a = 42, $.b) }
# OUTPUT:
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Cannot put required parameter $.b after optional parameters
```

So, a few questions: is destructuring assignment even *supposed* to work with `has`?  If so, is the behavior with default values correct/is there a way to assign default values when using destucturing assignment?

(I really hope that destructuring assignment *is* supported with `has` and can be made to work with default values; even though it might seem like a niche feature for someone using classes for true OO, it's *very* handy for someone writing more functional code who wants to use a class as a slightly-more-typesafe Hash with fixed keys.  Being able to write things like `class User { has (Str $.first-name, Str $.last-name, Int $.age) }` is **very** helpful for that sort of code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a [known bug](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4522) in Rakudo.  The intended behavior is for `has` to support [list assignment](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#Item_and_list_assignment), which would make syntax very much like that shown in the question work.

I am not sure if the supported syntax will be:

```raku
class D { has ($.a, $.b = 42) }
D.new: :a<foo>;  # OUTPUT: «D.new(a => "foo", b => 42)»
```

or

```raku
class D { has ($.a, $.b) = (Any, 42) }
D.new: :a<foo>;  # OUTPUT: «D.new(a => "foo", b => 42)»
```

but, either way, there will be a way to use a single `has` to declare multiple attributes while also providing default values for those attributes.

The current expectation is that this bug will get resolved sometime after the [RakuAST](http://jnthn.net/papers/2020-cic-rakuast.pdf) branch is merged.